# Filtered Stream never returning

Tags: java, twitter, java-11

I'm trying to build a bot using Twitter API. I'm testing [Filtered stream](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-search-stream) to read the latest tweets with some words.

To test I create a single rule with a trending topic from Brasil:

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "1360964144200110081",
            "value": "carnaval lang:pt",
            "tag": "Carnaval"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "sent": "2021-02-14T15:47:31.321Z"
    }
}
```

But when I execute the GET Stream `https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/api-reference/get-tweets-search-stream`, it never returns. I believe this can be a WebSocket, but I can't find that information on docs.

I'm doing a request on `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream?tweet.fields=created_at&expansions=author_id&user.fields=created_at` using the Authorization token and I'm getting 200 as a response, but the connection is never closed and no content.

I'm using the following code to call: [github.com/vepo/twitter4j](https://github.com/vepo/twitter4j)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

The problem is that I was expecting a String, but, as it is a WebSocket, the Response never ends. I change it to an InputStream and it starts working.